# How to navigate to different page while coming back from activity in WL.NativePage.show()?

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

My scenario is this: I am using `WL.NativePage.show(nativePageClassName, backFromNativePage, params)` to navigate to an activity. Once returning back to the WebView, I need to navigate directly to other page(Div) in html, rather from the page I originally navigated from to the activity, which is developed using jQuery-Mobile.

See the below example code.

```
WL.NativePage.show("com.example.SignatureActivity", function(data) {
                if(data.goToPage == "example2"){
                    $.mobile.changePage('#example2-page',{transition: 'none'});
                }else{
                    $.mobile.changePage('#example1-page',{transition: 'none'});
                }
            });
```

Here I am using WL.NativePage.show() In example1-page, I have two buttons in activity, one is save and one is back, while saving I need to navigate to example2 and while back, its example1.

I am able to navigate to example2, but example1-page is executing and displaying first and then displaying example2-page.

Please give me suggestions on how to navigate directly to example2-page without displaying example1-page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't navigate directly from the activity to a different place in the DOM which is in the WebView from which you navigated to the activity.

What you could do, is open displaying the activity, also hide the current content in the WebView. I assume it is a DIV essentially - so you could do something with display:none or any other standard method.

That way when the user returns back to the WebView from the activity and the code to change page is executed, you could then play again with the visibility of the DIV to display it when needed.

This way what you don't want to be seen will not be shown.